# how to attach a listener to a radio button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have an activity that displays various radiobuttons. The radiobuttons are grouped in radiogroups. I want some of the radiobutton to disappear when a certain radiobutton is checked. eg when the incident button is checked the fall, trip and illness radiobutton disappear. how can i achieve this?

I have the foolowing code but need to somehow attach a listener to the incident button.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.reportsomethinglayout);

         resolution = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextresolution);
        // resolution.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        // showSoftKeyboard(resolution);



         accident  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonaccident);
         incident  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonincident);
         concern  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonconcern);
         fall  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonfall);
         trip  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonTrip);
         illness  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonillness);





    }



     public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
            // Is the button now checked?
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.radioButtonaccident:
                    if (checked)
                        Log.e(TAG, "accident radiobutton checked");
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonincident:
                    if (checked)
                        Log.e(TAG, "incident radiobutton checked");

                            fall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            trip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            illness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/carefreebgscaledalphajpg" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutasscrollneedsonenamedchild" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/reportsomethingtitletextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Carer Reporting"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewcategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Category" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">   


     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonaccident"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Accident" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonincident"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Incident" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonconcern"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Concern" />

    </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewspacer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewtype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Type" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">   

     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonfall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fall" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonTrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Trip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonillness"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Illness" />

    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewspacer2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewaction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Action" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCallDoctor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call Doctor" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtoncalledkin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Called next of kin" />



    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewspacer3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewresolution"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Resolution" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextresolution"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="1"
        android:lines="8"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try like this:-

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
       {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(radiobutton1.isChecked()) {
             fall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             trip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             illness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if(radiobutton2.isChecked()) {

        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set a listener on a `RadioGroup` with `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. The `onCheckedChanged` callback receives the ID of the newly checked button in the `checkedId` parameter.

In your case, just add an ID to your radio group (in order to retrieve it from your code)

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/category_group"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

And use the following code:

```
RadioGroup categoryGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.category_group);
categoryGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    switch(checkedId) {
        case R.id.radioButtonincident:
            // 'Incident' checked
            fall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            trip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            illness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.radioButtonaccident:
            // 'Accident' checked
            break;
        case R.id.radioButtonconcern:
            // 'Concern' checked
            break;
        }
    }
});
```