# Radio button state not saving

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, radio-group

this is my code for displaying color for drawn analog clock,for this i have used rado group and used it through shared prefence in my live wallpaper,what ever the color i clicked is successfully applying to the clock, but the problem is after closing and again when returned to colorpicking window previous radio button state is not saved,can any one please help me to rectify the error

```
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean flag) {
    flag1=flag;
    super.onDialogClosed(flag1);
    if (flag1) {
        android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080001, 0xffffff);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080002, 0xc0c0c0);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080003, 0x808080);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080004, 0xff0000);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080005, 0xff8000);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080006, 0xffff00);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080007, 0x80ff00);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080008, 65280);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f080009, 65408);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f08000a, 65535);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f08000b, 33023);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f08000c, 255);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f08000d, 0x8000ff);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f08000e, 0xff00ff);
        saveRadioButton(editor, 0x7f08000f, 0xff0080);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

protected void saveRadioButton(android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor, int i, int j) {

    if (((RadioButton)mainView.findViewById(i)).isChecked()) {
        editor.putInt(getKey(), j);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to writing so many method call , `view.getId()` will return specific id ,and  u have only saving values in SharedPreferences. you should get value from SharedPreferences on proper place .

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `editor.commit();` after

```
editor.putInt(getKey(), j);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Try using RadioGroup Checkchange listener instead of RadioButton, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529361/how-to-attach-a-listener-to-a-radio-button