# How to implement setOnClickListener to get selected value from dynamically created RadioButton Android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have a dynamically created radio buttons inside a `RadioGroup` since the values are coming from the database. I want to be able to implement `setOnClickListener` so I can get the whatever the selected value is. Whenever I try to click on the radio button, nothing shows up.

```
public void viewAll() {

    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

    LinearLayout bg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.backgroundSM);
    LinearLayout display = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewAllMsg);

    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    res.moveToFirst();

    for(int i=0; i<res.getCount(); i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),res.getString(1) + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        rb[i].setText(" " + res.getString(1)
                + "    " + res.getInt(0));
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        res.moveToNext();
    }

    display.addView(rg); // add the whole RadioGroup to the layout

    rg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                rg.removeView(rb[i]); // now the RadioButtons are in the RadioGroup
            }

            int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id + " worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}
```

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You might want to set individual click listeners to the RadioButtons rather than one listener to the entire group view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529361/how-to-attach-a-listener-to-a-radio-button/

Comment: For clarity, `View.OnClickListener` is for the entire view. You want a `OnCheckedChangeListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selected position will be saved in `position` variable

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (radioGroup.getChildAt(i).getId() == id) {
                    position = i + 1; //+1 is used to have a start value of 1 like your example
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply! Thank you so much for this, I can get the value now.